# How to stop specific docker instance based on browser close or tab close event?

Tags: docker, containers, x11, novnc, websockify

A Java Swing application is dockerized and it is bundled with fluxbox,X11 and noVNC(websockify)application(see reference). Whenever user clicks a html it opens and browser tab and starts a fresh Java Swing application for this request. It works as expected but I want to stop the specific docker instance when the user close the tab or browser window. How to stop the specific docker with respect to that tab?

Reference - *https://hub.docker.com/r/psharkey/novnc*